# express js route is not working, getting a 404 for some reason

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a link that is suppose to go to a page but every time I click on the link the address changes to the right page but I get a 404 Not Found error.

app.js

```
  var express = require('express');
  var path = require('path');
  var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
  var logger = require('morgan');
  var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
  var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
  var fs = require("fs");


  var routes = require('./routes/index');
  var login = require('./routes/login');
  var rtc = require('./routes/rtc');
  var adminEstimating = require('./routes/adminEstimating');
  var adminEWJ = require('./routes/adminEWJ');
  var adminTrusses = require('./routes/adminTrusses');
  var admin = require('./routes/admin');
  var adminMillwork = require('./routes/adminMillwork');
  var adminInsulation = require('./routes/adminInsulation');
  var adminDrywall = require('./routes/adminDrywall');
  var submitted = require('./routes/submitted');
  var adminLink = require('./routes/adminLink');
  var notAdmin = require('./routes/notAdmin');
  var error = require('./routes/error');
  var dogReport = require('./routes/dogReport');
  var fleetReport = require('./routes/fleetReport');
  var fleetLogin = require('./routes/fleetLogin');
  var fleetNotAdmin = require('./routes/fleetNotAdmin');
  var fleetAdminLink = require('./routes/fleetAdminLink');
  var fleetAdminNew = require('./routes/fleetAdminNew');


  var app = express();

  // view engine setup

  app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');

  var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
  app.locals.ENV = env;
  app.locals.ENV_DEVELOPMENT = env == 'development';

  // app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/img/favicon.ico'));
  app.use(logger('dev'));
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
  }));
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

  app.use('/leadtime/', routes);
  app.use('/leadtime/', function(req, res, next){
    var fileName = './public/components/visitorTracker.json';
    var fileContent = fs.readFileSync(fileName);
    var content = JSON.parse(fileContent);
    content.visitorCount++;
    fs.writeFileSync(fileName, JSON.stringify(content));
    next();
  });
  app.use('/leadtime/login', login);
  app.use('/leadtime/rtcProduction', rtc);
  app.use('/leadtime/adminEstimating', adminEstimating);
  app.use('/leadtime/adminEWJ', adminEWJ);
  app.use('/leadtime/adminTrusses', adminTrusses);
  app.use('/leadtime/admin', admin);
  app.use('/leadtime/adminMillwork', adminMillwork);
  app.use('/leadtime/adminInsulation', adminInsulation);
  app.use('/leadtime/adminDrywall', adminDrywall);
  app.use('/leadtime/submitted', submitted);
  app.use('/leadtime/adminLink', adminLink);
  app.use('/leadtime/notAdmin', notAdmin);
  app.use('/leadtime/error', error);
  app.use('/dogReport', dogReport);
  app.use('/fleetReport', fleetReport);
  app.use('/fleetReport/fleetLogin', fleetLogin);
  app.use('/fleetReport/fleetNotAdmin', fleetNotAdmin);
  app.use('/fleetReport/fleetAdminLink', fleetAdminLink);
  app.use('/fleetReport/fleetAdminNew', fleetAdminNew);
```

The route that isn't working is `var fleetAdminNew = require('./routes/fleetAdminNew');`

I've done the same thing for all my other routes and have had no problems. I've looked for spelling mistakes and I haven't found any.

fleetAdminNew.jade

```
  extends layout

  block content
    div(class='container')
      header
        h1 National Lumber Co. / Reliable Truss & Component
        h2 Fleet Maintenance Administration
      div(class='section')
        h3 New Truck
        form(method='POST')
          label(for='yard') Yard
          input(type='text' id='yard')
          label(for='vehicle#') Vehicle #
          input(type='text' id='vehicle#')
          label(for='vehicleDescription') Vehicle Description
          input(type='text' id='vehicleDescription')
```

fleetAdminNew.js (not finished yet, still need to put post code in)

```
  var express = require('express');
  var fs = require("fs");
  var router = express.Router();

  /* GET home page. */

  router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('fleetAdminNew', { title: 'Add New Truck' });
  });

  module.exports = router;
```

Comment: in your `router.get` at `fleetAdminNew.js` put some `console.log` to debug if nodejs is executing this part of code.

Comment: I added `console.log("I'm working");` before `res.render('fleetAdminNew', { title: 'Add New Truck' });` but I got nothing in the console.

Comment: I just spotted another post that put .js at the end of the files in the routes of app.js `var fleetAdminNew = require('./routes/fleetAdminNew.js');` not sure why that helped when I don't need it for the others but I'll add the file extension to the rest and call it solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a folder 'routes/fleetAdminNew' then it's pulling the nothing from that instead.

Comment: I added in a fleet subfolder to the route folder and put them in there and pointed to that and it seems to work fine. Thanks.